# java swing display part of image

Tags: image, swing

I need to display part or point of an image in a java swing, does anyone could help me to resolve the problem. I can display the whole image, but do not know how to display part or point of the image, could anyone help me, please. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ImageIO` to read your image into a `BufferedImage`.

Then you can use `BufferedImage.getSubImage(...)` method get part of the image to display.